# WebStorm not finding some node globals in TypeScript files

Tags: node.js, typescript, webstorm

I'm working with Typescript >=2.0 on WebStorm 2016.2.2

When I use some node globals like `__dirname` or `process`, WebStorm is claming:
`Corresponding file is not included in tsconfig.json`

I have the Node.js Core library enabled. To affirm that it is enabled, I ran `JSON.stringify` and WebStorm was able to bring up all possible arguments lists. It's also worth mentioning that all of my code compiles fine, the editor errors are just an eye sore.

Comment: Hi. Could you please share your tsconfig.json settings?

Comment: @anstarovoyt Your comment reminded me that I need to include the node types somewhere.

I could do this by including a `node.d.ts` in the `files` section of my `tsconfig.json`. Instead, with Typescript 2.0, I'm favoring running a `npm install --save-dev @types/node`